# Using jQuery's .load method to return one element from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and JS and I encounter what I believe is a syntax problem, but I haven't been able to fix it on my own.

I am using the .load method to display content on a page, which works perfectly when I use the following bit of code :

```
$("#mydiv1 a")on('click', function ()
{
$("#mydiv2").load(this.href); 
});
```

When calling this.href, however, the entire page is returned (as expected). I would like to be able to return only one element in this page: #myelement. This is where my problem occurs: the following code doesn't work.

```
$("#mydiv1 a")on('click', function ()
{
$("#mydiv2").load(this.href #myelement); 
});
```

If my syntax is indeed incorrect, what would be the right way to put it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Keep your browser developer console open so that you can see reported errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a string:

```
$("#mydiv2").load(this.href + " #myelement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to write it:

```
$("#mydiv2").load(this.href + ' #myelement');
```